# get Fatal Error on eval()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im making a project that will execute a PHP code in a string..Since im not using any PHP compiler or interpreter..I decided to use eval() function.. Im using Codeigniter Framework

MY CODE

CONTROLLER

```
$code  = $this->input->post('code');
$functionCall = $this->input->post('funCall');
$expOut = $this->input->post('expectedOutput');
$integrate = $code." ".$functionCall;
     ob_start();
     eval($integrate);
     $ret = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();

if($ret === $expOut){
        //all work fine
   }
else{
    redirect('main/wrongCode');
    }
 }
```

Everything work fine but when the output is fatal error..it will not execute the `redirect('main/wrongCode');`..
Is there's a way to get the fatal error? So i can make a condition?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: im using 5.4.12..xD OR jst 5..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use PHP Exception Handling

```
try{
     ob_start();
     eval($integrate);
     $ret = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();
}catch(Exception $e) {
     echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
if($ret === $expOut){
     //Do sth
}
else{
    // Do sth else
}
```

have a look at [PHP Exceptions](http://php.net/exceptions)

Comment: THANKS..i got it now..it really working..im just make a function exception handler inside the object buffering..:) thanks for your idea..:)

Comment: This could work in PHP7 if you `catch( ParseError $e )`, an alternative for PHP 5 is using `php -l` as shown in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141295/is-there-any-way-to-catch-fatal-error-using-eval/36944015#36944015