# Is there any way to catch eval fatal error in php?

Tags: php, exception, eval, fatal-error

Im executing the list of php codes via eval, If there is any error in code i want to display this code have fatal error/parse error.

is there any way to give custom message for fatal error or any other error

My code is like this :

```
$output = [];
foreach($codes as $key => $res) {

    if(eval($res['code'])) {
        eval($res['code']);
        $output[$key] = $result;
    } else {
        $output[$key]  = "Fatal error in code";             
    }       
}
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: maybe useful? [Handle fatal errors in PHP using register_shutdown_function()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410632/handle-fatal-errors-in-php-using-register-shutdown-function). Actually, quite useful. It is really useful for debugging 'awkward' issues that are triggering fatal errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way!  Write the code to a file, using `php -l` in the eval, then delete the file.  See my answer for example code:

[Is there any way to catch fatal error using eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141295/is-there-any-way-to-catch-fatal-error-using-eval/36944015#36944015)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to expect `Throwable`:

```
try {
    ...
    @eval(...);
    ...
} catch(Throwable $t) {
    ...
}
```